# sed counting lines incorrect

Tags: file, sed, lines, counting

Running sed for counting lines in my file returns 1, but Sublime and Textedit count more than 88000 lines. Why does sed do that? How can I fix it?

```
$sed -n '$=' out_data1.txt
1
```

I use sed to count lines of a very large file ~10GB of mongodb query result to split it later for multithread.

Comment: My first suspect is an anomalous end of line character that `sed` doesn't detect correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You command should work, but try:

```
wc -l out_data1.txt
```

or just for test

```
awk 'END {print NR}' data1.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

sed have some buffer limit but try (i don't recommand sed on huge file especially just for counting lines)

```
sed -u -n "$="
```

maybe a `"s/.*//;$="` if there is also a buffer problem on line size itself